# Contacts not shown saved from phonegap in Xperia J

Tags: cordova, sony-xperia

with reference to the following thread..

[Can't see contacts that was saved with phonegap on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906136/cant-see-contacts-that-was-saved-with-phonegap-on-android)

i want to ask that.
i am saving contacts from my phonegap app to Xperia J. But i can not see the saved contacts.
However when i m retrieving the saved contact and printing it in alert, i can see it.

What is wrong? Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: @darshan for both.. Phonegap will take care i guess !!

Comment: Phonegap Developer chat : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11300/phonegap-framework

Answer (score 0):

First add few contact in your device ...

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    // find all contacts with 'Bob' in any name field
    var options = new ContactFindOptions();
    options.filter="Bob"; 
    var fields = ["displayName", "name"];
    navigator.contacts.find(fields, onSuccess, onError, options);

unction onSuccess(contacts) {
    for (var i=0; i<contacts.length; i++) {
        console.log("Display Name = " + contacts[i].displayName);
    }
}



 // onError: Failed to get the contacts
//
function onError(contactError) {
    alert('onError!');
}


}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Gamex.. i have added contacts in my phone and then used your script to retrieve it.. i am able to see the contacts. But my question is when i am saving a contact from my phonegap application then i am not able to view in my contact list, although i can retrieve it by using a similar script like yours..

Comment: Yes, you can follow above script for retrive contact

Comment: did u check ontacts.length ?

Comment: @ Darshan.. yes.. i can alert the name of the contact also.. but its not showing in my mobile contacts list !!

Comment: Same problem occurs in xperia-U.